# How to trace the root of an stopifnot in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix, breakpoints, trace

I have the following program:

```
four.in.a.row = function(player, v, debug=FALSE) {
  if (debug) {
    cat(sep="", "four.in.a.row(player=", player, ", v=", v, ")\n")
  }
  with(rle(v), any(lengths== 4 & values == player))
}
won = function(player, board, r, c, debug=FALSE) {
  if (debug) {
    cat(sep="", "won(player=", player, ", board=\n")
    print(board)
    cat(sep="", ", r=", r, ", c=", c, ")\n")
  }
  row=x[r,]
  print(row)
  col=x[,c]
  print(col)
  reverse_diag=x[row(x) + col(x) == r + c]
  print(reverse_diag)
  diag=x[row(x) - col(x) == r - c]
  print(diag)
  four.in.a.row(player,row,debug=FALSE)
  four.in.a.row(player,col,debug=FALSE)
  four.in.a.row(player,diag,debug=FALSE)
  four.in.a.row(player,reverse_diag,debug=FALSE)

  return(FALSE) 
}


x = matrix(data=c(
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","E",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","E",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","E",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","E",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","E",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","E"
), nrow=6, ncol=7, byrow=TRUE)
stopifnot(!won(player="X", board=x, r=1, c=1, debug=TRUE))
stopifnot(!won(player="O", board=x, r=1, c=1, debug=TRUE))
stopifnot(!won(player="X", board=x, r=2, c=3, debug=TRUE))
stopifnot(!won(player="O", board=x, r=2, c=3, debug=TRUE))

x = matrix(data=c(
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","O",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","O",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","O",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","O",
  "E","E","E","E","E","E","X",
  "X","X","X","X","O","E","X"
), nrow=6, ncol=7, byrow=TRUE)
stopifnot( won(player="X", board=x, r=6, c=1, debug=TRUE))
stopifnot(!won(player="O", board=x, r=6, c=1, debug=TRUE))
stopifnot(!won(player="X", board=x, r=1, c=7, debug=TRUE))
stopifnot( won(player="O", board=x, r=1, c=7, debug=TRUE))
```

And I receive this error (while I don't expect it):

```
> source("rle.R")
won(player=X, board=
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[2,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[3,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[4,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[5,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[6,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
, r=1, c=1)
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
won(player=O, board=
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[2,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[3,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[4,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[5,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[6,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
, r=1, c=1)
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
won(player=X, board=
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[2,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[3,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[4,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[5,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[6,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
, r=2, c=3)
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
won(player=O, board=
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[2,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[3,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[4,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[5,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
[6,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
, r=2, c=3)
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
won(player=X, board=
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "O" 
[2,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "O" 
[3,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "O" 
[4,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "O" 
[5,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "X" 
[6,] "X"  "X"  "X"  "X"  "O"  "E"  "X" 
, r=6, c=1)
[1] "X" "X" "X" "X" "O" "E" "X"
[1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "X"
[1] "X" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[1] "X"
Error: won(player = "X", board = x, r = 6, c = 1, debug = TRUE) is not TRUE
```

Is there a quick way to step through/breakpoint stopifnot or any other method to trace what's wrong? Beside do you know why I get the wrong answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
debugonce(won)
```

before rerunning the particular call that gives an unexpected output, and walk through the code.

That's one approach among multiple debug methods, see `debug`, `browser`, `recover`...

Most likely the problem comes from `won` always returning `FALSE`: the `four.in.a.row` calls above `return(FALSE)` will not make the function exit and `return(TRUE)`. Instead, you want to make it return:

```
return(four.in.a.row(player,row,debug=debug)  ||
       four.in.a.row(player,col,debug=debug)  ||
       four.in.a.row(player,diag,debug=debug) ||
       four.in.a.row(player,reverse_diag,debug=debug))
```

Or this if you find it easier to understand:

```
if (four.in.a.row(player,row,debug=debug))          return(TRUE)
if (four.in.a.row(player,col,debug=debug))          return(TRUE)
if (four.in.a.row(player,diag,debug=debug)          return(TRUE)
if (four.in.a.row(player,reverse_diag,debug=debug)) return(TRUE)
return(FALSE)
```

I also notice `won` is using `x` when it should use the `board` argument.

Comment: @floderl Can you please take a look at this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586098/error-in-x-1l-x-n-comparison-of-these-types-is-not-implemented

Comment: What is debug=debug? Because I either have debug=TRUE or debug=FALSE

Comment: Both functions take a `debug` argument. From inside `won`, we call `four.in.a.row` with `debug=debug` so that the `debug` value within `won` is passed down to `four.in.a.row`.

Comment: Can you please take a look at other post? I updated it as you mentioned but yet I receive the error as in title. I guess that is a problem with vector length not being the same

Comment: Everything works for me. I don't understand how you got that error.